# Can't rename a .part file apache2 webdav server

Tags: apache-http-server, nas, webdav, file-server

I have an apache2 server with WebDAV enabled. I can rename and move anything as long as it doesn't end with .part. when I try I get a 404. I can rename a file to end in .part and I can delete and open the file just can't move or rename it. The server is only http and everything is chmod 775 and owned by www-data. I don't know what I can do to fix this.

Here is my sites-enabled/webdav.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Alias /svn /var/www/webdav/svn
        <Location /svn>
                DAV On
        </Location>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/webdav
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/webdav/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```